# Angular Fire Imports angular 13

Tags: angular, firebase, package.json, angularfire

I try to import the AngularFireModule and the AngularFirestoreModule but it says

```
Module '"@angular/fire/firestore"' has no exported member 'AngularFirestoreModule'.
Module '"@angular/fire"' has no exported member 'AngularFireModule'.
```

Here is what I've got in my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TaskComponent } from './components/task/task.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TaskComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ], 
  providers: [DatePipe],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

These are my versions:

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.7
"@angular/fire": "^7.2.0",
"firebase": "^9.8.2",
```

Heres the table for the version compatibility
[compatibility](https://github.com/angular/angularfire#compatibility)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how you are using the AngularFire app, the locations of things have changed.  With the newer version, the AngularFire libraries can be tree-shaken.  However, to use the old methods, there is a compatibility layer.

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
```

becomes:

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire/compat';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
```

[AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire)